# Make a request to API and parse response

Tags: json, bash, api, curl, jq

I am trying to create a bash script in order to search jobs from  " The GitHub Jobs API " https://jobs.github.com/api

When the user runs the script :

```
./search_job.sh "Python" "New York"
```

the required output is :

```
{
"company": "The Public Theater",
"title": "Web Developer"
}
{
"company": "Aon Cyber Solutions",
"title": "Cybersecurity Firm Seeks Senior Developer"
}
{
"company": "Sesame",
"title": "Software engineer (back end)"
}
{
"company": "New York University",
"title": "Technology Solutions Developer"
}
```

I have tried to create the script using curl and jq commands.

```
curl -sS https://jobs.github.com/api \
  | jq -r --arg name "Python" \
    '.location[] | if .name == $name then .id else empty end'
```

Comment: Maybe you could also post the script you tried to do and describe where or what exactly fails with what errors, this would help people to help you.

Comment: I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `-G` and `--data-urlencode` you can get curl to make a proper call to API. Parsing the response with jq is the trivial part.

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -G --data-urlencode "description=$1" \
        --data-urlencode "location=$2"    \
https://jobs.github.com/positions.json | jq '.[] | { company, title }'
```